# circuitikz drawing help needed

Tags: circuitikz, circuits

Are there any generators that help with drawing circuits?

More or less R2 is supposed to be a rhetostat but i really have no idea how to code a drawing.

[image: redited to make it look better]

edited to make circuit little better (drew it in illustrator), i am trying to include it as a pdf but coming out lousy figure the circuit drawing method would be pretty cool nevertheless.

Comment: What have you tried? Right now, this is just a do-it-for-me. You can export Ti*k*Z code from Inkscape. You can find plenty of examples on this site and elsewhere. You can find the manual for `circuitikz`. Not sure what else there is to say at this stage. Until you have a specific question it's hard to help.

Comment: Documentation is lacking, I didn't mean it as a do-it-for-me, just something to get started.  But I can draw, as seen above, I did it in Illustrator, so besides including a pdf/eps, the circuit tool seems intriguing as it can save steps, but until I learn to hard-code it, a way to draw it in a program, and export, since I don't think inkscape has circuit templates.  I used digikey's schemit and exported the svg into illustrator in order to tweak a few things.  if that is the best method, then i'll leave it as that, and close the question.

Comment: There certainly is documentation. There is the package's manual, for example. There are numerous examples on this site and elsewhere in addition. You can import SVG into Inkscape and export Ti*k*Z code. It won't be pretty but it usually works.